# When the default value is 0 in widget configuration, the integer stepper setting behavior makes no sense

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I have created a widget that has two configurable options, one is a boolean, and it works well, and the other one is an integer that makes problems. This is my current parameter's configuration:

[image]

Whenever I create this widget, “plus days” is not set to 0, but to -2. Or any value I put in the minimum field. If the default value is different from 0, everything works well.

I also tried to use Field instead of Stepper, but then both minimum and maximum values are ignored, regardless of what values I put in there.

I also noticed that setting a value in here to 0 removes tags from the XML, so I tried to keep them with value 0, but it also didn't do the trick.

Is it a bug or desired behavior? And is there a workaround for this?